# Basics of using ArcSDE

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I need to access tables which are in an Oracle database by ArcCatalog. I am new to this ArcMap software, so please suggest to me detailed steps to access database tables from ArcMap.

Answer (score 4):

There are too many questions to ask to give an answer.
First the "normal" use for sde is to utilize the rdbms as a spatial geo-database.
1. If your data already existing in oracle is "that", then you are looking in the right direction.

If 1 is yes then you will need to configure sde to work with (maybe sdo) the data format that your oracle tables exist in.

If not then the question begs...
Do you have spatial data?  Or do you simply have business tables you want to link with spatial data in another db/ or format (shapefile).

If you can enlighten us and expand on your question maybe we can get you to the next level.
In the meantime any extra time you have could be spent on the resources page at arcgis.com.